# Como chamar initLoader dentro de OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

Oi, é possível chamar um initLoader dentro de um OnClickListener?

Preciso que ele seja iniciado após a entrada de dados do editText, pois a requisição de rede retorna erro 400, URL entra sem a consulta do usuário, pois a variável não foi passada no método OnClick, os parametros do initLoader apresenta erro no **this**, diz que é requerido LoaderCallBacks e não OnClickListener.

```
package com.example.android.listadelivros;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements LoaderCallbacks<List<DadosLivro>> {

    private static String pesquisarDadosLivro;
    private DadosLivrosAdapter mAdapter;

    private static final String GOOGLE_LIVROS_URL =
            "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q= " + pesquisarDadosLivro;
    ;

    private static final int DADOSLIVROS_ID_LOADER = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button pesquisarLivro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pesquisar);
        pesquisarLivro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                EditText dadosLivro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dados_livro);
                pesquisarDadosLivro = dadosLivro.getText().toString();

                final LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
                loaderManager.initLoader(DADOSLIVROS_ID_LOADER, null,
                        this);
            }
        });

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

        mAdapter = new DadosLivrosAdapter(this, new ArrayList<DadosLivro>());

        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public android.content.Loader<List<DadosLivro>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        return new DadosLivrosLoader(this, GOOGLE_LIVROS_URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader<List<DadosLivro>> loader, List<DadosLivro>
            informacoesLivros) {

        if (informacoesLivros != null && !informacoesLivros.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter.addAll(informacoesLivros);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(android.content.Loader<List<DadosLivro>> loader) {
        mAdapter.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorre pois dentro do `OnClickListener`, o contexto é outro!

Dentro do método onclick, seu this é um OnClickListener e não um `LoaderCallbacks`!

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
pesquisarLivro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            EditText dadosLivro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dados_livro);
            pesquisarDadosLivro = dadosLivro.getText().toString();

            final LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
            loaderManager.initLoader(DADOSLIVROS_ID_LOADER, null,
              //Vamos usar o this de MainActivity!!!
                    MainActivity.this);
        }
    });
```

Existe mais um problema no seu código:

```
private static final String GOOGLE_LIVROS_URL =
            "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q= " + pesquisarDadosLivro;
```

Esta url sempre irá adiconar `null` pois ela é criada antes de atualizar a variável `pesquisarDadosLivro`

Tente da sequinte forma:

```
// Vamos transformar %s em o que o usuário digitou no campo!
    private static final String GOOGLE_LIVROS_URL =
                "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=%s" ;
```

Quando invocar seu LoaderManager, vamos passar o texto q o usuário adicionou!

```
// Vamos encodar a String para adicionar na url 


 final String encodeParam = URLEncoder.encode(pesquisarDadosLivro, "utf-8"));
// Alteramos o %s por encodeParam;
    final String _url = String.format(DADOSLIVROS_ID_LOADER, encodeParam);

loaderManager.initLoader(_url, null,
 //Vamos usar o this de MainActivity!!!
    MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Meu Deus, era uma coisa tão idiota '_' desculpa.

Comment: Não precisa se desculpar! Estamos aqui para ajudar! =)

Comment: Que bom, o problema é que a URL continua indo sem a variável inclusa na consulta, chega como null e volta com erro 400.

Comment: ei amigo, consegui, o problema era o espaço em branco na url, fiz um teste e deu certo, agora preciso resolver caso o usuario informe mais de uma palavra para que não haja espaços em branco e o erro retorne

Comment: pq ñ pode ter espaços?

Comment: Então, use o URLEncoder! ele vai transformar espaços em **+**! tipo assim: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=tomates+verdes_fritos

Comment: pq se for com espaços volta erro 400 o 404 :/ tenso

Comment: Legal, vou ver a respeito sim, funcionou em algumas palavras que testei e outras apresentou esse erro: Object has been collected Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString()

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58273/discussion-between-thiago-luiz-domacoski-and-aline-ramos).